# Can not get CSS animation to work in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

I cannot get my animation to animate in my [Shopify page](https://www.allabouttoytrains.com/pages/about-us). As you can see it is static and not moving how it should. I have decompiled the SASS to CSS, I have no errors in the inspect element tool. I am using the exact code from Codepen, I have the CSS in the theme.scss.liquid folder. So I'm stumped on why it's not working any help is appreciated.

https://codepen.io/marvindanig/pen/avLRJz

html

```
<div class="toy-train">
  <div class="engine">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="engine-main">
        <div class="smokes">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="engine-body">
      <div class="wheels">
        <div class="big-wheel"></div>
        <div class="normal-wheel"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="locomotive">
    <div class="trash"></div>
    <div class="wheels">
      <div class="normal-wheel"></div>
      <div class="normal-wheel"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tracks">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#about-us{

    body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1A2980 10%, #26D0CE 90%);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .toy-train {
    position: relative;
    width: 11vw;
  }

  .engine {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
  }

  .window {
    height: 2.8vw;
    width: 3vw;
    background-color: #194488;
    position: relative;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .window:before,
  .window:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .window:before {
    height: .7vw;
    background-color: #F82510;
    width: 4.5vw;
    margin-top: -1.3vw;
    margin-left: -2.6vw;
    border-radius: .8vw;
  }

  .window:after {
    margin-left: -.8vw;
    margin-top: .3vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.1vw;
    width: 1.1vw;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .engine-main {
    height: 1vw;
    width: 3.5vw;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    background-color: #3D9A01;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 .8vw .8vw 0;
    right: -4.1vw;
    bottom: -.3vw;
  }

  .engine-main:before {
    content: "";
    height: 1vw;
    width: .8vw;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.1vw;
    left: .4vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 90% 90% 40% 40%;
  }

  .engine-main:after {
    content: "";
    height: 1.2vw;
    width: .8vw;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: .5vw;
    top: -1.8vw;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 90% 90% 40% 40%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #194488;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .engine-body {
    height: 1.7vw;
    width: 7.5vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: -.2vw;
    top: 3.0vw;
    background-color: #F69F00;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    border-radius: .5vw;
  }

  .engine-body .big-wheel {
    top: .3vw;
    left: .2vw;
  }

  .engine-body .normal-wheel {
    left: 4.5vw;
    top: .5vw;
  }

  .engine-body:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: .5vw;
    width: .5vw;
    left: -1.1vw;
    bottom: .2vw;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .wheels > div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F82510;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    -webkit-animation: wheel-rotate 1s linear infinite;
            animation: wheel-rotate 1s linear infinite;
  }

  .wheels > div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: .1vw solid #000;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.1vw;
  }

  .wheels > div:after {
    content: "";
    height: .8vw;
    width: .8vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -.4vw;
    margin-top: -.4vw;
  }

  .wheels .big-wheel {
    width: 2.2vw;
    height: 2.2vw;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
            animation-delay: -0.3s;
  }

  .wheels .normal-wheel {
    height: 2.0vw;
    width: 2.0vw;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }

  .locomotive {
    height: 3.5vw;
    width: 6.0vw;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    background-color: #F69F00;
    border-radius: .5vw;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1.3vw;
  }

  .locomotive:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #000000 8%, #f69f00 8%, #f69f00 15%, #000000 15%, #000000 28%, #000000 34%, #f69f00 34%, #f69f00 65%, #000000 65%, #000000 65%, #000000 100%);
    height: .3vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: .6vw;
    left: 0;
  }

  .locomotive:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #000000 24%, #f69f00 24%, #f69f00 65%, #f69f00 65%, #000000 65%, #000000 85%, #f69f00 85%, #f69f00 90%, #000000 90%, #000000 100%);
    height: .3vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.4vw;
    left: 0;
  }

  .locomotive .wheels > div {
    top: 2.2vw;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }

  .locomotive .wheels > div:first-child {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
            animation-delay: -0.9s;
  }

  .locomotive .normal-wheel:first-of-type {
    left: .2vw;
  }

  .locomotive .normal-wheel:last-of-type {
    right: .2vw;
  }

  .locomotive .trash {
    height: 3.5vw;
    width: 5.0vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8vw;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    background-color: #3D9A01;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: .2vw;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .tracks {
    position: relative;
    width: 20vw;
    bottom: -1vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: .3vw;
  }

  .tracks span {
    display: inline;
    height: .3vw;
    width: 20vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vw;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 39%, black 39%, black 61%, black 65%, transparent 65%, transparent 70%, black 71%, black 100%);
    -webkit-animation: track 2s linear infinite;
            animation: track 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .tracks span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
            animation-delay: -1s;
  }

  .smokes:before,
  .smokes:after,
  .smokes span:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: .8vw;
    width: .8vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: .8vw;
    top: 1.5vw;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .smokes:before {
    -webkit-animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
            animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
  }

  .smokes span:before {
    -webkit-animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
            animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }

  .smokes:after {
    -webkit-animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
            animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
            animation-delay: -0.3s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes smoke {
    100% {
      top: -5vw;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }

  @keyframes smoke {
    100% {
      top: -5vw;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes wheel-rotate {
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
              transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes wheel-rotate {
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
              transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes track {
    100% {
      left: -20vw;
    }
  }

  @keyframes track {
    100% {
      left: -20vw;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: There are many stylesheets that are included in your `<head>`. Could you specify the link that references to above mentioned stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just close the first selector or remove it:

`#about-us{` to `#about-us{}`

```css
#about-us{}

    body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1A2980 10%, #26D0CE 90%);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .toy-train {
    position: relative;
    width: 11vw;
  }

  .engine {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
  }

  .window {
    height: 2.8vw;
    width: 3vw;
    background-color: #194488;
    position: relative;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .window:before,
  .window:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .window:before {
    height: .7vw;
    background-color: #F82510;
    width: 4.5vw;
    margin-top: -1.3vw;
    margin-left: -2.6vw;
    border-radius: .8vw;
  }

  .window:after {
    margin-left: -.8vw;
    margin-top: .3vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 1.1vw;
    width: 1.1vw;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  .engine-main {
    height: 1vw;
    width: 3.5vw;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    background-color: #3D9A01;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 .8vw .8vw 0;
    right: -4.1vw;
    bottom: -.3vw;
  }

  .engine-main:before {
    content: "";
    height: 1vw;
    width: .8vw;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.1vw;
    left: .4vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 90% 90% 40% 40%;
  }

  .engine-main:after {
    content: "";
    height: 1.2vw;
    width: .8vw;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: .5vw;
    top: -1.8vw;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 90% 90% 40% 40%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #194488;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .engine-body {
    height: 1.7vw;
    width: 7.5vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: -.2vw;
    top: 3.0vw;
    background-color: #F69F00;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    border-radius: .5vw;
  }

  .engine-body .big-wheel {
    top: .3vw;
    left: .2vw;
  }

  .engine-body .normal-wheel {
    left: 4.5vw;
    top: .5vw;
  }

  .engine-body:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: .5vw;
    width: .5vw;
    left: -1.1vw;
    bottom: .2vw;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
  }

  .wheels > div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F82510;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    -webkit-animation: wheel-rotate 1s linear infinite;
            animation: wheel-rotate 1s linear infinite;
  }

  .wheels > div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: .1vw solid #000;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.1vw;
  }

  .wheels > div:after {
    content: "";
    height: .8vw;
    width: .8vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -.4vw;
    margin-top: -.4vw;
  }

  .wheels .big-wheel {
    width: 2.2vw;
    height: 2.2vw;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
            animation-delay: -0.3s;
  }

  .wheels .normal-wheel {
    height: 2.0vw;
    width: 2.0vw;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }

  .locomotive {
    height: 3.5vw;
    width: 6.0vw;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    background-color: #F69F00;
    border-radius: .5vw;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1.3vw;
  }

  .locomotive:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #000000 8%, #f69f00 8%, #f69f00 15%, #000000 15%, #000000 28%, #000000 34%, #f69f00 34%, #f69f00 65%, #000000 65%, #000000 65%, #000000 100%);
    height: .3vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: .6vw;
    left: 0;
  }

  .locomotive:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #000000 24%, #f69f00 24%, #f69f00 65%, #f69f00 65%, #000000 65%, #000000 85%, #f69f00 85%, #f69f00 90%, #000000 90%, #000000 100%);
    height: .3vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.4vw;
    left: 0;
  }

  .locomotive .wheels > div {
    top: 2.2vw;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }

  .locomotive .wheels > div:first-child {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
            animation-delay: -0.9s;
  }

  .locomotive .normal-wheel:first-of-type {
    left: .2vw;
  }

  .locomotive .normal-wheel:last-of-type {
    right: .2vw;
  }

  .locomotive .trash {
    height: 3.5vw;
    width: 5.0vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1.8vw;
    border: .3vw solid #000;
    background-color: #3D9A01;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: .2vw;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .tracks {
    position: relative;
    width: 20vw;
    bottom: -1vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: .3vw;
  }

  .tracks span {
    display: inline;
    height: .3vw;
    width: 20vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vw;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 39%, black 39%, black 61%, black 65%, transparent 65%, transparent 70%, black 71%, black 100%);
    -webkit-animation: track 2s linear infinite;
            animation: track 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .tracks span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
            animation-delay: -1s;
  }

  .smokes:before,
  .smokes:after,
  .smokes span:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: .8vw;
    width: .8vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: .8vw;
    top: 1.5vw;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .smokes:before {
    -webkit-animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
            animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
  }

  .smokes span:before {
    -webkit-animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
            animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
            animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }

  .smokes:after {
    -webkit-animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
            animation: smoke 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
            animation-delay: -0.3s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes smoke {
    100% {
      top: -5vw;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }

  @keyframes smoke {
    100% {
      top: -5vw;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes wheel-rotate {
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
              transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes wheel-rotate {
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
              transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes track {
    100% {
      left: -20vw;
    }
  }

  @keyframes track {
    100% {
      left: -20vw;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="toy-train">
  <div class="engine">
    <div class="window">
      <div class="engine-main">
        <div class="smokes">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="engine-body">
      <div class="wheels">
        <div class="big-wheel"></div>
        <div class="normal-wheel"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="locomotive">
    <div class="trash"></div>
    <div class="wheels">
      <div class="normal-wheel"></div>
      <div class="normal-wheel"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tracks">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that made it run but I had it in the about-us ID to contain those classes to that specific page. Would you be able to tell me why it does not run when wrapped in the brackets?

Comment: @RyderThacker If this is the output CSS from SASS my guess there is a problem in your SASS which needs to be fixed. I mean as @ JustinT. mentions the last bracket. It means that everything is nested like in SASS which obviously doesn't work in CSS.